# Getting HTTP error 407 while sending http get request [Android]

Tags: android

I have following code to send request to get one test file using one URL.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, httpContext);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

But when i execute this code i get error code as `407`, but i i try to download this URL using the browser of the device then it does work and i am able to download the file.

Is it that i need to add in proxy setting to this request object before sending request?
Or is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Have a look to understand: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E407.html

Comment: The status code 407 refers to Proxy Authentication. You have to pass in your credentials for the proxy in the `Proxy-Authenticate` header field.